# Could not align the image inside a label to the right

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to set the alignment of an image inside a label without success.

I have set the text to the right successfully by choosing Arabic on the localization option using Xcode.
But the image doesn't seem to work.

This is my contructView function:

```
- (void)constructAlertCardView {
    UIView* alertView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    alertView.backgroundColor = _alertViewBackgroundColor;
    [self.view addSubview:alertView];

    CGFloat heightCorrection = _alertPosition == ISAlertPositionBottom ? -10.f : (_statusBarHeight > 0.f ? _statusBarHeight : 10.f);

    CGFloat insetCorrection = 0;
    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        if (_alertPosition == ISAlertPositionBottom) {
            UIWindow *window = UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow;
            insetCorrection = -window.safeAreaInsets.bottom;
        }
    }

    UIImageView* iconImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kDefaultInset, (_alertViewHeight - _iconImageSize.height + heightCorrection + insetCorrection) / 2.f, _iconImageSize.width, _iconImageSize.height)];
    iconImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    iconImage.image = _iconImage;
    iconImage.isAccessibilityElement = true;
    iconImage.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitButton;
    iconImage.accessibilityLabel = NSLocalizedString(@"OK", comment: "");
    [alertView addSubview:iconImage];

    heightCorrection = heightCorrection + (_alertPosition == ISAlertPositionBottom ? 10.0f : insetCorrection + (_statusBarHeight > 0.f ? (_statusBarHeight / 4) : 0.f));

    UILabel* titleLabel = [UILabel new];
    titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake((kDefaultInset*2.f) + _iconImageSize.width, kDefaultInset + heightCorrection, self.view.frame.size.width - ((kDefaultInset*3.f) + _iconImageSize.width), _titleLabelHeight);
    titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    titleLabel.textColor = _titleLabelTextColor;
    titleLabel.font = _titleLabelFont;
    titleLabel.text = _titleString;
    if (self.alertTypeAcessibilityLabel != nil) {
        titleLabel.accessibilityLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", self.alertTypeAcessibilityLabel, _titleString];
    }
    [alertView addSubview:titleLabel];

    UILabel* messageLabel = [UILabel new];
    messageLabel.frame = CGRectMake((kDefaultInset*2.f) + _iconImageSize.width, kDefaultInset + heightCorrection + _titleLabelHeight + 3.f, self.view.frame.size.width - ((kDefaultInset*3.f) + _iconImageSize.width), _messageLabelHeight);
    messageLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    messageLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    messageLabel.textColor = _messageLabelTextColor;
    messageLabel.font = _messageLabelFont;
    messageLabel.text = _messageString;
    [alertView addSubview:messageLabel];

    // Sets custom order of accessibility elements.
    alertView.accessibilityElements = @[iconImage,titleLabel, messageLabel];

    if (_hideOnSwipe) {
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer* swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureAction)];
        swipeGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
        [alertView addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];
    }

    if (_hideOnTap) {
        UITapGestureRecognizer* tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureActionWithHandler)];
        [alertView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    }

}
```

Comment: "But the image doesn't seem to work" What does that mean? What happens, and what were you hoping for?

Comment: @matt it goes to the left side

Answer (score 0):

In an app that supports both arabic and english, I too faced similar problem where I had to show image before label in English language.

So instead of UILabel, I used UIButton's property and set its image. I also disabled user interaction of button so that it gives feel of Label.

[image]
Once done, based on the language selected, you can **adjust the title insets and image insets** of this UIButton to fine tune spacing of image.

```
    if(isArabicLanguage){
        [button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -20, 0, 0)];
    }else{
        [button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 0)];
    }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Arabic is an RTL(right to left language) So, you have to align image as per RTL or LTL language your code will work properly in LTL language but for RTL language you have aligned the image in reverse side.

Comment: That's true as far as it goes, but you have not explained how to do that.